# Emgucv + SURF feature

Tags: emgucv

I am using emgucv2.3. 
When I type the line `MCvSURFParams surfParam = new MCvSURFParams(500, false);` , I get the error `The type or namespace name 'MCvSURFParams' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`    .  But I have included all necessary references. Can anyone tell where I am wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your using an old call to the code it should now be:

```
SURFDetector surfParam = new SURFDetector(500, false);
```

Assuming you have the correct references and using statements this will work, refere to the SurfFeature example in 2.3.0 to check your code.

Cheers,

Chris